# How to add my custom .d.ts file to my angular library?

Tags: angular, typescript-typings, yeoman-generator, tsconfig

I've created angular library using Yeoman generator library (https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library). Then I want to add files with my custom types and place them into src/types folder, but compiler doesn't see them.

I've tried to use different paths in types, typeRoots in tsconfig.es5.json, but no luck yet.

Created a simple repo reproducing the problem: 
https://github.com/yuriykuzin/ng2-sample-library

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: also created an issue: https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/94

Answer (score 5):

The compiler uses `src/index.ts` as the main entry point to figure out which files to compile.

If your types are not imported in one of your project files, you will have to add the following line to `src/index.ts` to tell the compiler to include the types:

```
import './types/sample-type';
```

This should result in `dist/types/sample-type.d.ts` being generated and referenced in `dist/index.d.ts`.

Comment: Important addition: You have to use `.ts` instead of `.d.ts`, otherwise the files won't be included.